# How to use this overriding on betterlistview?

Tags: .net, vb.net, listview, overriding, ownerdrawn

I've been working with BetterListView and I asked the devs if changing the color of the selection was possible. Here's their reply:

> you can customize selection using Owner Drawing. This requires
>   subclassing BetterListView and drawing custom selection instead of the
>   default one:
>
> ```
> public class CustomListView : BetterListView
> {
>     protected override void OnDrawItem(BetterListViewDrawItemEventArgs eventArgs)
>     {
>         if ((eventArgs.ItemStateInfo.ItemState & BetterListViewItemState.Selected) == BetterListViewItemState.Selected)
>         {
>             // draw custom selection
>             eventArgs.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Brown, eventArgs.ItemBounds.BoundsSelection);
>         }
>
>         eventArgs.DrawSelection = false; // disable drawing default selection
>
>         // default drawing (image, text etc.)
>         base.OnDrawItem(eventArgs);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Please note the eventArgs.ItemStateInfo.ItemState is a flags enum,
>   i.e. the item can be hot, focused and selected independently and
>   drawing of the custom selection may need to include these states for
>   better user experience. The default selection uses Windows Theme so it
>   is displayed the same way as in Windows Explorer.

Upon reading this I tried to understand how to use this overriding, but I never did such a thing. Despite, reading a lot about OwnerDrawing and Overriding, I am still confused.

Here's the code translated to VB.Net and the two other selection type added :

```
Imports ComponentOwl.BetterListView

Public Class CustomBetterListview

    Inherits BetterListView
    Protected Overrides Sub OnDrawItem(eventArgs As BetterListViewDrawItemEventArgs)

        If (eventArgs.ItemStateInfo.ItemState And BetterListViewItemState.Selected) = BetterListViewItemState.Selected Then
            ' draw custom selection
            eventArgs.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Brown, eventArgs.ItemBounds.BoundsSelection)
        End If

        If (eventArgs.ItemStateInfo.ItemState And BetterListViewItemState.Focused) = BetterListViewItemState.Focused Then
            ' draw custom selection
            eventArgs.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, eventArgs.ItemBounds.BoundsSelection)
        End If

        If (eventArgs.ItemStateInfo.ItemState And BetterListViewItemState.Hot) = BetterListViewItemState.Hot Then
            ' draw custom selection
            eventArgs.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, eventArgs.ItemBounds.BoundsSelection)
        End If

        eventArgs.DrawSelection = False
        ' disable drawing default selection
        ' default drawing (image, text etc.)
        MyBase.OnDrawItem(eventArgs)
    End Sub

End Class
```

I suppose I'm on the right way, but I can't figure this out... it seems I'm missing a few fundamentals. I should probably mention that I'm trying to override BetterListViews placed on the form in design mode, as I suspect could possibly be a problem?

Comment: Is there a problem with the result?

Comment: You need to use CustomBetterListView on your form, and not BetterListView.  Once you have created your derived control, you need to use that instead of the base control.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not seeing the custom control in my toolbox list. How would I add it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've searched a bit about adding a custom control and it seems like rebuilding the project places the control at the top of the toolbox. Everything's working now.

Thanks for helping out.